# How is "enum InstanceType" ordered in objects.h in V8?

Tags: c++, enums, v8

I'm confused by something in the source code of V8.

In **objects.h**, there is enum InstanceType which describes the type of the instances. And part of it is defined for JS Type, such as date and array.

```
enum InstanceType {
  ...

  // All the following types are subtypes of JSReceiver, which corresponds to
  // objects in the JS sense. The first and the last type in this range are
  // the two forms of function. This organization enables using the same
  // compares for checking the JS_RECEIVER/SPEC_OBJECT range and the
  // NONCALLABLE_JS_OBJECT range.
  JS_FUNCTION_PROXY_TYPE,  // FIRST_JS_RECEIVER_TYPE, FIRST_JS_PROXY_TYPE
  JS_PROXY_TYPE,  // LAST_JS_PROXY_TYPE

  JS_VALUE_TYPE,  // FIRST_JS_OBJECT_TYPE
  JS_DATE_TYPE,
  JS_OBJECT_TYPE,
  JS_CONTEXT_EXTENSION_OBJECT_TYPE,
  JS_MODULE_TYPE,
  JS_GLOBAL_OBJECT_TYPE,
  JS_BUILTINS_OBJECT_TYPE,
  JS_GLOBAL_PROXY_TYPE,
  JS_ARRAY_TYPE,
  JS_SET_TYPE,
  JS_MAP_TYPE,
  JS_WEAK_MAP_TYPE,

  JS_REGEXP_TYPE,

  JS_FUNCTION_TYPE,  // LAST_JS_OBJECT_TYPE, LAST_JS_RECEIVER_TYPE

  ...
};
```

Then I see a static check of JS_OBJECT_TYPE. Here Internals::kJSObjectType is defined as 0xaa in v8.h.

```
STATIC_CHECK(JS_OBJECT_TYPE == Internals::kJSObjectType);
```

So, how is the TYPEs ordered in InstanceType? Why is JS_DATE_TYPE before JS_OBJECT_TYPE and JS_ARRAY_TYPE after it?

If it is arbitrarily ordered, why does V8 check the number of JS_OBJECT_TYPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main reason is to correctly fall to runtime when you use indexing operator on either `JS_VALUE_TYPE` or `JS_OBJECT_TYPE`, generated code does not handle it correctly. See [`GenerateKeyedLoadReceiverCheck`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/ia32/ic-ia32.cc?r=13473#247).

The check in `v8.h` is verifying that constants manually exported from the V8 and used through inline functions in this public API file match internal constants. `v8.h` can't depend on the internal `objects.h` thus it has these constants duplicated. Without the check those inlined functions will start breaking in the bizarre ways if somebody changes `objects.h` but forgets to update `v8.h`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So if I want to add a new type similar to Array, is it OK to just add JS_MYOBJ_TYPE after JS_ARRAY_TYPE in the list? I've added a new `class JSMyObj`in objects.h/cpp.

Comment: @jean I don't know what are you trying to achieve that requires adding things to V8's internal object model, but yes if you need an instance type you can put it there. It does not matter whether you put it before or after JS_ARRAY_TYPE.

Comment: @jean but why do you need a new class? Public API has indexed interceptors support to allow embedder create array-like structures. https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/include/v8.h&q=v8.h&sq=package:v8&type=cs&l=2493

Comment: I want to take advantage of some internal methods in V8, so I'm trying this way. Thank you very much.